# IIS url rewrite role except some urls

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I got this rule in URL rewrite that rewrites every request to the site using HTTP to HTTPS

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

I need another rule or exception in this role to rewrite back or redirect specific urls to HTTP.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can add the exceptions for which you don't want to perform the redirect to HTTPS as extra conditions (not equal to that URL), like so:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/noredirect/forthis/page\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/noredirect/forthis/page-as-well\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/noredirect/forthis/page-as-well-too\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: its gonna be like this >>  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/domain.com/directoryname/pageName\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" /> , ?thanks for reply

Comment: As long as domain.com is a directory in the root directory of you website, then yes, that will work. Note that you should use `domain\.com` in the regular expression to literally match domain.com otherwise the dot will make the regular expression accept any character there. You can not use this if you intend to match against domain.com as a domain name because the domain name is not included in the `{REQUEST_URI}` variable.

Comment: I used the IIS Wizard to exclude a specific domain from the URL writing and it turned out to create a line like this:

            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*SubStringOfURLToExclude.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />

in the condition node. While SubStringOfURL is a sub string of the URL I want to exclude.

Comment: Also try taking `negate="true"` off the tag... that worked for me

Comment: So happy this is a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Exception rule in Web.config, to not redirect the "NotSecurePage.ashx" to https:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="\bNotSecurePage.ashx\b" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" /> <!-- Crystal não suporta imagens https.. Criando exceção para imagens de barcode, utilizadas no crystal -->
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```