# Auto redirect to https using IIS Url Rewrite Moduleexcept one route

Tags: url, iis, https, url-rewriting

I want all incoming http requests for my ASP.NET site to be redirected to **https** requests **except the following route which I want to be served using http**:

**http://example.com/asdf**

where 'asdf' can be replaced with any combination of alphanumeric characters

I am using IIS Url Rewrite module.

Comment: Have you made any research? I found a similar question as the first result from a google search...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS url rewrite role except some urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320614/iis-url-rewrite-role-except-some-urls)

Comment: Thanks GoTo - you referred to the exact link. Unfortunately I didnt find that in my search :)

Comment: For the record I searched for "url rewrite exception" :)